UK standard visitor visa sponsorship
We are planning to apply for UK visit visa, We will be visiting family in the UK as well.
I have a fixed deposit that is sufficient to sponsor for the trip, which will be maturing in a months time. I  can provide proof for monthly income as well, which is a very small amount.
My husband has a business registration and business that is active recently, he is also employed however he gets his salary as cash in hand.
Based on these circumstances is it advisable to use my father (who resides in my home country and has sufficient funds) as a sponsor for
our trip?
Also if he is sponsoring should I transfer the sponsored funds to my account before applying ?

The problem is going to be with your monthly income. If it is very small, why are you spending a big part of your savings to visit the UK on vacation? Why would your father give you money to visit the UK on vacation when instead he could be buying you food or paying you rent?

There are already a lot of questions on TSE on this topic. The red flags of a very small income and a recently established business with a cash in hand salary, plus family in the UK, are not going to be offset by having your father sponsor you IMHO.

The UK government has these checks in place to ensure that people are travelling to the UK for legitimate reasons (ie business or leisure). If you're coming for leisure, they'll want to be sure you can support yourself whilst there and that you have strong ties to go home. It's difficult give you an answer on exactly what you need and what would be enough. However,
If you're visiting family I'd want addresses, phone numbers, correspondence from them.
In terms of money you would want the money in your account so you can access it, ideally as much as you can find. If you have some kind of budget or itinerary written up that would help.
Finally you want to prove that you intend to return home, return flights, proof of a home (ie a mortgage or rental contract) or any kind of paperwork from a job would help.
As the other commenter said, even with that you could still be challenged on why you've chosen to make an expensive trip with a low income. You really need a good answer for that!

Having your father sending money into your account before you apply for the visa is not the way to go, as immigration officers are likely to assume that it is a loan only to get the visa, and to be repaid before you travel. His promise to pay and proof of funds for him should work as well or better.

I suggest you review this question and its extensive and complete answer for more insight about how UKVI will assess your visa application.
